# Linux Mint 64-bit Kernel Panic on Boot

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, kernel-panic

I'm trying to install 64-bit Maya on the new Macbook Pro with Retina Display using a Bootcamp partition.

The trouble is that I get a kernel panic similar to the one below on live cd boot or usb boot. I did manage to get Maya to boot using "recovery mode". I even managed to install Maya however when I tried to boot from that partition, I got the same kernel panic.

Does any one know whats going on?

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing the same on:
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P7450 @ 2.13GHz
It is definitely not related to a bad media I have tried several times as well.Both DVD and USB. I will return with an answer as soon as I can working on it now

Answer (score 1):

Your CD/DVD drive could be SOL. I've had more disk drives go out on me than I have had iso images be corrupt. But then again I am usually very meticulous about hash and burn checking my ISOs. Most of the time I am trying to install Linux on an older computer that has long since had the drive compromised by dust. It might start to read the disk, and have a boot menu come up, but that doesn't mean at all that the disk drive can successfully read the whole disk.

Does your Mac OS boot and run fine? If that doesn't, then perhaps you have more than just a disk drive hardware problem.

Comment: no, tried download the image a few times... unless Linux Mint's 64-bit image online is corrupt! I've tried burning a DVD and a USB! Mac OSX runs just fine. the laptop is brand new!

Comment: Did you check the hash of the iso image? I am not a mac user, so I can't really help you with finding a hashing program, but they do have MD5 hashs on the website for you to verify with

Answer (score 0):

Probably that live cd or usb or image file(.iso) is corrupted. Try to get new cd or usb or .iso .

Comment: no, tried download the image a few times... unless Linux Mint's 64-bit image online is corrupt! I've tried burning a DVD and a USB!